# Calculating CRC using with slice 8 algorithm when number of bits not multiple of 8

Tags: c++, crc, crc32, crc16

I am to implementing CRC24C calculation using slice by 8 algorithm. I have successfully implemented for the case when number data bits is multiple of 8. however when number of input bits is not multiple of 8, slice by 8 algorithm fails. I am planning to split the data bits into two parts, one part contains # of data bits which is multiple of 8 and another part contains remaining bits. calculate the CRC24C individually and combine it. however i am not able to figure out a way to combine two individually calculated CRC's. Any suggestions or ideas will be very helpful.

Comment: I am doing implementation in c++ so i though it is relevant

Comment: You can just add zero bits until number if data bits is multiple of 8. If you want your hash to be different for case if there are actually zeroes on those places, find something else to add.

Comment: I have tried appending zeros but it is resulting in different CRC value than correct.

Comment: @V.Kravchenko Thanks a lot for the suggestion, I was appending zeros in the LSB side of integer it was resulting in different CRC, after appending zeros in MSB side of integer i am getting correct CRC.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple function to compute the first few and/or the last few bits of the CRC, depending on how your data is laid out in memory. I don't know which 24-bit CRC you're using, but for this one:

```
width=24 poly=0x864cfb init=0xb704ce refin=false refout=false xorout=0x000000 check=0x21cf02 residue=0x000000 name="CRC-24"
```

this C code will update `crc` with the high `bits` bits in the low byte of `val`:

```
unsigned crc24_rem(unsigned crc, unsigned val, unsigned bits) {
    val &= 0x100 - (0x100 >> bits) ;
    crc ^= (unsigned)val << 16;
    while (bits--)
        crc = crc & 0x800000 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0x864cfb : crc << 1;
    crc &= 0xffffff;
    return crc;
}
```

You can use [crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany) to generate code like this for any CRC definition.

---

Comment: This appears to have an off-by-one error in 'bits'.  For example bits=1, then `while(bits--)`, executes twice. Also, I think that it is expected that 'val' has valid bits in the higher values. Or the API is 'bits-1' of valid bits.  I have it working in verilog and with boost, but still trying to duplicate with just simple 'C'.  However, this was helpful.  I have a protocol where only the low 7 bits (ascii clean type) is significant.  So, crc  is stronger over only real data.  Cleanliness is a double check.  Crc is 14bits in my case (also 'clean').

Comment: @artlessnoise I don't know what you mean by "has valid bits in the higher values". The line of text above the code explicitly states which bits in `val` are applied to the CRC. All the other bits in `val` get zeroed out, and so do not matter.

Comment: @artlessnoise No. You need to think through more carefully what `while (bits--)` does. If `bits` is one, then the body of the while executes once.

Comment: Thanks.  I see the API is the same as crcany generated source.  Yes, I am wrong about the loop.  I mean for 'val' is it the higher bits that are used or the lower grouping.  The answer is the higher part.  The comment is a little confusing.  'val' could be uint8_t and then 'low byte' wouldn't matter.